# Delete field's machine-name in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I'm trying to create a new field, but Drupal came up with the well-known error:

> The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique

I'm sure that the field doesn't exist anymore (I checked the fields' list and it doesn't show up). I want to use that specific machine name because I already have developed some functions that are using that name.

So I guess the name is still saved in the database, there is a way to delete it without screw everything up?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you run cron recently?

Comment: Have you checked that database have table with that field name ?

Comment: Did you delete that field manually from database, instead of deleting from UI? If yes clear cache and try again

Comment: First make sure that the field is completely deleted (no leftovers), and than purge the field. `field_delete_field($field_name); field_purge_batch(1000);`